# Multiple columns, conditions for only one

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to list multiple columns but specify a condition for only one.. e.g

```
SELECT max(dollars_spent), customer as most_visits FROM example
```

I want the customer to display IF they have the most dollars spent but don't know how to specify I want that condition for that specific column only.. I'm tired and am struggling to process this right now. Hoping someone out there will understand what I mean.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - and do 2 columns count as 'multiple'?

Answer (score 0):

This may work...

`select sum(dollars_spent), customer as most_visits from example group by customer order by sum(dollars_spent) desc limit 1`